# sql insert into asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user(Firstname,Lastname,Email,Pass,Type)
    values(@first,@last,@email,@pass,@type)",con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@first",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtfirst.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@last",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtlast.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtemail.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtpass.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@type",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "customer";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

what is the problem with my syntax it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'."

Comment: show us your connection string. Nothing wrong with the SQL. Seems like your connection string isn't set correctly to point to a particular DB

Comment: Also, please use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` instead of the deprecated `cmd.Parameters.Add()`

Comment: and yes `user` is a keyword. JW. gave the solution

Answer (score 11):

you should escape the table name `user` with delimited identifiers,

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [user] (Firstname,Lastname,Email,Pass,Type) values(@first,@last,@email,@pass,@type)",con);
```

- [SQL Server Reserved Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)
- [SQL Server Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

**UPDATE 1**

Refractor your code by

- using `using` statement to properly dispose objects
- using `Try-Catch` block to properly handle exceptions

code snippet:

```
string _connStr = "connectionString here";
string _query = "INSERT INTO [user] (Firstname,Lastname,Email,Pass,Type) values (@first,@last,@email,@pass,@type)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = _query;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", txtfirst.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", txtlast.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "customer");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            // other codes here
            // do something with the exception
            // don't swallow it.
        }
    }
}
```

- [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [Add (*recommended one*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)

Comment: Try use stored procedures and input validation will save you headaches down the line.

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on SQL Server.

You should use your table name with brackets `[]` like;

```
INSERT INTO [user]
```

You can try like;

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [user] (Firstname,Lastname,Email,Pass,Type) values(@first,@last,@email,@pass,@type)",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", txtfirst.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", txtlast.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "customer");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

And also like [@JW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537278/447156) said, it is always a good approach to using them in a try-catch statement.

- [Best Practices of Exception Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9795/Best-Practices-of-Exception-Management)